# I want to navigate to different page, but router.navigate is not working in subscribe method

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, mongodb, express

//I want to redirect to another page after the subscribe method, but //router.navigate not working in subscribe method.

//I tried storing the data coming from subscribe into a variable but the //variable is being declared undefined

```
onAddCustomer() {
    this.bill.addCustomer(this.form.value).subscribe(data => {
      this.router.navigate[`/addBill/${data.data._id}`];
    });
  }
```

//I want to navigate to addBill page after adding the customer with the //customer id which i am getting from the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`router.navigate` is a function, and in the syntax of your example, you are trying to access a property of the navigate function.

Basically, I think you're missing parenthesis:

```
this.router.navigate([`/addBill/${data.data._id}`]);
```